# inserting into postgresql decimal field fails with error "cannot convert {125.00} to Int2"

Tags: postgresql, go, pgx

I am fairly new to golang. I am trying to insert into a postgresql table which has a numeric field, using a web app gin-gonic.

```
postgres=# \d user_txns;
                       Table "public.user_txns"
   Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 user_id     | character varying(15) |           | not null |
 txn_code    | smallint              |           | not null |
 description | character varying(64) |           | not null |
 txn_amount  | numeric(15,4)         |           | not null |
 txn_type    | smallint              |           | not null |
 voucher     | character varying(16) |           |          |
```

I am using jackc pgxpool to insert into the table as below.

```
109 ▏ sql := `INSERT INTO user_txns VALUES ($1,$2, $3, $4, $5)`
▎ 110 ▏ _, err = tx.Exec(context.Background(), sql,
▎ 111 ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ claims["phone"],
▎ 112 ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ recharge,
▎ 113 ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ "User recharge",
▎ 114 ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ recharge.Amount,
▎ 115 ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ ▏ credit,
▎ 116 ▏ )
▎ 117 ▏ if err != nil {
▎ 118 ▏ ▏ c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"msg": err.Error()})
▎ 119 ▏ ▏ return
▎ 120 ▏ },
```

The payload is a json request that has the following structure:

```
{
  "amount": 125.00 
}
```

I unmarshal the request into a struct defined as below.

```
type Recharge struct {
  Amount string `json:"amount" binding:"required"`
}
```

The insert fails with error

> "msg": "cannot convert {125} to Int2"

What is the right golang data type to use for inserting into a decimal field?

thanx

Comment: [`jackc/pgtype.Numeric`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Numeric)

Comment: Now, I get a new error  "json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Recharge.amount of type pgtype.Numeric"

Comment: Hi @mkopriva can you kindly help me with an example pls.

Comment: JSON value `125.00` cannot be unmarshaled into Go `string`. Please provide the actual code, e.g. is `"125.00"` (type string) in the JSON? Or is it `Amount float64` in Go? Also the error you're showing does not seem to align with the insert example, e.g. if `recharge.Amount` is of type `string` then it would be very unusual for the error message to render is at `{125}` (unless the curly braces were part of the string inside the JSON).

Comment: I tried with all combinations like string, int64 etc.  But the same result.  Here is the link to the go playground. https://go.dev/play/p/Jqse8vD66g-

Comment: I've ran the code in the answer below and all three examples execute without issues. If you're still unable to make it work then the problem may have nothing to do with `numeric`, instead the problem may be somewhere else in your code. In that case you should provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to insert a value like `125.00` into a postgres column of type `numeric` would be to use a float type in Go. This works out of the box and so there's no need to implement any kind of custom interface.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
    , amount numeric(15,4) NOT NULL
    -- ...
);
```

```golang
data := []byte(`{"amount": 125.00}`)
var obj struct {
    Amount float64 `json:"amount"`
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

_, err := db.Exec(`INSERT INTO t (amount) VALUES ($1)`, obj.Amount)
```

---

Float types are subject to rounding errors however, and because of that a common practice for storing monetary amounts is to use integers that represent the value *in cents*. E.g. `125.00` becomes `12500`. This also works out of the box.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
    , amount int8 NOT NULL
    -- ...
);
```

```golang
data := []byte(`{"amount": 12500}`)
var obj struct {
    Amount int64 `json:"amount"`
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

_, err := db.Exec(`INSERT INTO t (amount) VALUES ($1)`, obj.Amount)
```

---

If you want to use the [`pgtype.Numeric`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgtype#Numeric) for storing and retrieving the amount to and from the database then you'll have to do some extra work because `pgtype.Numeric` doesn't know how to encode/decode JSON `125.00`/`"125.00"` values.

One thing you can do is to declare a custom struct type, have it *embed* the `pgtype.Numeric` type, and then have the custom struct type implement the `json.Marshaler` and `json.Unmarshaler` interfaces.

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY
    , amount numeric(15,4) NOT NULL
    -- ...
);
```

```golang
type MyNumeric struct {
    pgtype.Numeric
}

func (n *MyNumeric) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s json.Number
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return n.Numeric.Set(s.String())
}

func (n MyNumeric) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var f float64
    if err := n.Numeric.AssignTo(&f); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return []byte(strconv.FormatFloat(f, 'f', -1, 64)), nil
}
```

```golang
data := []byte(`{"amount": 125.00}`)
var obj struct {
    Amount MyNumeric `json:"amount"`
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

_, err := db.Exec(`INSERT INTO t (amount) VALUES ($1)`, obj.Amount)
```

Comment: My silly mistake. I realized that I declared an enum with the same name as unmarshaling type.  const recharge was clashing with var recharge of type Recharge struct {}.  Unfortunately there was no  compilation error.